# npm run watch in docker compose

Tags: npm, docker-compose, laravel-mix, browser-sync

Im using **Laravel Mix** to build assets (css,js) , When i run `npm run watch` without using docker it work with opening a new browser Tab to watch changes for css and js files.

But when using docker , i run this command `docker compose run --rm npm run watch` i got this error :

```
[Browsersync] Couldn't open browser (if you are using BrowserSync in a headless environment, you might want to set the open option to false)
```

**My webpackconfig.mix.js**

```
miw.browsersync({
proxy:'http://localhost:8008',
port:3001,
files:[public/*.css,public/*.js]
})
```

**my docker-compose.yaml**

```
image:node:latest
working_dir:/src
entrypoint:['npm']
ports:
  -3001:3001
command : ["npm","run","dev","prod","watch"]
```

Is there any recommandations to watch changes in the browser .Thanks